# How do I apply only one file or two classes from a Puppet Master server?

Tags: puppet, configuration-files, configuration-management

Let us say that I have a case in which I need to apply only two files from a Puppet configuration on some production servers, without touching the rest of the configuration.

/opt/aservice/myfile/thekey.conf
/opt/myfile/thekey.salt

Let's also say that these are controlled by the following Puppet manifest:

```
#
# author: Nathan Basanese (nathan@basanese.com)
# date: 04/17/2048
#

class keyconfig ( $cluster ){
    notify {"Deploying key config. files to $fqdn":}


    file {'/opt/aservice/key/config/thekey.conf':
                ensure => present,
                mode => '0644',
                owner => 'aservice-serv',
                group => 'aservice-serv',
                source => "puppet:///modules/keyconfig/$cluster/thekey.conf",
        }
    file {'/opt/aservice/key/config/thekey.salt':
                ensure => present,
                mode => '0644',
                owner => 'aservice-serv',
                group => 'aservice-serv',
                source => "puppet:///modules/keyconfig/$cluster/thekey.salt",
        }
}
```

How would I apply ONLY these two files to a given server from a Puppet Master?

Perhaps, in the `puppet agent` command that is run on the target server, could I specify a specific Puppet class to use?

I have used the [`puppet resource`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/4.3.0/man/resource.html) command before, but I'm not sure that would work, here.

Answer (score 5):

Every resource is automatically [tagged](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_tags.html) with the fully qualified name of the class or defined type in which it is declared, and with every namespace  segment of the class or type name, among other tags.  You can use those tags to filter the resources that will be applied during a given catalog run.  In the particular example you describe, you could use

```
puppet agent --no-daemonize --onetime --tags keyconfig
```

to apply only the resources declared in class keyconfig (and in any other class declared by keyconfig, recursively, but in this case there are no such other classes).

You can also declare tags manually by using the `tag` metaparameter in your resource declarations.  That can allow you to provide for identifying custom collections of resources.  And speaking of collections, you can use tags in the selection predicates of resource collectors, too.

Comment: // , Wow, I did not know about that! I'm taking a course on Puppet, soon, for obvious reasons. I'll have to see if they include such features in the curriculum. The answers to this (honestly sort of silly) question have really surprised me.

Comment: Yep, I completely brain-farted on tags, this is a perfect usecase for them, this is a better answer!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is to have that node contain only the class you are wanting to have applied. In your site.pp you would have the following where the 'myhost.dns' is your fqdn. and $mycluster would be replaced by your cluster string.

```
node 'myhost.dns' {
    class { 'keyconfig':
      cluster => $mycluster,
    }
}
```

Comment: // , Thanks for the quick answer, @Travis! If I had, let's say, two classes, though, could I selectively apply just one, by a change to the `puppet agent` command, without modifying anything on my Puppet Master?

Comment: This is just wrong.  Tags can be used to accomplish the OP's objective.